# Triple integral equals to a negative value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

I have been working on the same problem for hours and originally I thought I finally achieved the answer and then I realized I converted the function to cylindrical coordinates improperly.

Now, on my next try I ended up with a negative value and I'm not sure if that is a reasonable answer (I feel like it isn't) or if I integrated to the wrong bounds.

$I = \iiint z(x+y) dV$, E is the region bounded by:

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$

$x^2 + y^2 = 4$

$z = x^2 + y^2$

the z-y plane and to the left of y-z plane (integrating the portion that lies in the second and third quadrant)

MUST BE CONVERTED FROM RECTANGULAR TO CYLINDRICAL THEN EVALUATED.

Converting to cylindrical:

$x = rcos\theta$ , $y = rsin\theta$

$z(x+y) = z(rcos\theta + rsin\theta)$

Integral (NOT DEFINITE IF THESE ARE CORRECT):

$I = \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_1^2 \int_0^{r^2} z(rcos\theta + rsin\theta) rdzdrd\theta$

$I = \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_1^2 \int_0^{r^2} zr^2(cos\theta + sin\theta)dzdrd\theta$

$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_1^2 z^2 |^{z=r^2}_{z=0} r^2(cos\theta + sin\theta)drd\theta$

$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_1^2 r^6(cos\theta + sin\theta)drd\theta$

$I = \frac{1}{14}\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} r^7|^{r=2}_{r=1} (cos\theta + sin\theta)d\theta$

$I = \frac{127}{14}(sin\theta - cos\theta)|_{\theta=\pi/2}^{\theta=3\pi/2}$

$I = \frac{127}{14}(sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}) - cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}))-(sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) - cos(\frac{\pi}{2}))$

$I = \frac{127}{14}(-1 - 0)-(1 - 0)$

$I = -\frac{127}{7}$ <--- negative?!?

Comment: What does it mean " and to the left of y-z plane"?

Comment: @user Means that the portion of the solid to be integrated is the portion to the left of the y-z plane. So I mentioned in parentheses that it would be the portion in the second and third quadrant.

Comment: Yes finally I realized what you mean, maybe it should be stated the region with $z\ge 0$ and $x\le 0$. If I'm not wrong with the intepretation, I've proposed a set up for that. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: Negative value is fine since we are assuming $x\le 0$ in the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the set up should be

$$\int_0^1 \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_1^{2} z(r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta) r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz+ \int_1^4 \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_{\sqrt z}^{2} z(r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta) r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$$

or as an alternative by your set up

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_1^{2} \int_0^{r^2}  z(r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta) r\,dz\,dr\, d\theta=-\frac{127}7$$

and the result seems correct indeed we are assuming $x\le 0$ in that region.

Comment: From the one you are showing, isn't the second integral for theta rather than r? And I'm not understanding overall why that is the setup.

Comment: @Amai Yes sorry I need to reorder the variables.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it in the order $dzdrd\theta$? That is how all the images I drew and what I was taught to integrate by.

Comment: @Amai Yes of course we can also do in that other way! I add that one

Comment: Thank you! I thought it couldn't be a negative value. Do you happen to know what exactly I'm integrating for? I believe double integrals would be volume, but I'm not very certain about triple. Just out of curiousity since it is possible to get a negative value.

Comment: @Amai Yes of course we can get negative value exactly as for the (signed) area in 2D integrals. We take into account sign also for volume.

Comment: Okay! Once again thank you! When I researched more triple integral often represents mass, and the idea of negative mass just seems to break my common logic which made me hesitate. I really appreciate the clarification and assistance!

Comment: @Amai When the function under the integral is positive the result is always positive as for the case with $b>a$, $\int_a^b 1 dx=b-a$. Since the density is positive an integral for teh mass is always positive. But for centroid or other quantities it is not the case as you know.